# find the $\lim: \lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{4} +...+ \sqrt{n})/(\sqrt[1.5]{n})$

Tags: limits

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{4} +...+ \sqrt{n})/(\sqrt[3/2]{n})$

yes, Stolz-Cesàro does give 2/3, but is there a solution possible using only 12th grade mathematics?(L'Hopital, substitution, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider

$\displaystyle {\int_{1}^{n}}√xdx= (2/3)x^{3/2}\big ]^n_1.$

Comment: i can see the link, but shouldn't there be any indiscrepancy in the summation of continuous values of a function and the discrete values of function?

Comment: Rashmi.Have a look at a proof of the " Integral comparison test for series".Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Riemann sum for $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ over $[0,1]$ .